# Really weird behavior of JavaScript of 'undefined' variable becoming a number?

Tags: javascript, null, numbers, undefined, settimeout

So... I was initially trying to create my own debouncing function, **but let's put that aside for now because I have a completely new problem (I think).**

Below code will render random number and I can't figure out why. Could someone please explain what's going on here?

```
<body>

<button id='butto'>Click</button>

<script>
let buttonz = document.querySelector('#butto');

buttonz.addEventListener('click',function(){
    let aaa;
    console.log(aaa);             //outputs 'undefined' - expected
    
    if (aaa){
        clearTimeout(aaa);
        console.log(aaa);
    }
    
    aaa = setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log('clicked');
        aaa = undefined;
        console.log(aaa);          //outputs 'undefined' - expected
    }, 2000);
    
    console.log(aaa);              // outputs 'random number' - ????????????????
    console.log(typeof aaa);       // outputs 'Number' - ????????????????
});

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: That "random number" is the timeout's ID, which is what you're using to clear it elsewhere. See e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout. What did you *expect* from `aaa = setTimeout(...)`?

Comment: oh I see, I expected 'function' as an output. So I guess setTimeout assigns random number instead of declared variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a number because because of this line:

`aaa = setTimeout(...)`

setTimeout returns a number. See docs: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp